# Undefined method _path when controllers combined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a PokemonBattles controller in which I have methods create, new and update. Everything works fine with new but not with update. The error I get when I try to access the edit view.

```
undefined method `pokemon_battle_path' for 
#<#<Class:0x007f692e7251c0>:0x007f692e7202d8>

Did you mean?  pokemon_battles_path
```

controller/pokemon_battles_controller.rb

```
def create
    pokemon_a = Pokemon.find(params[:pokemon_battle][:pokemon_a_id])
    @pokemon_battle = PokemonBattle.create(pokemon_a_id: pokemon_a.id, 
        match_status: :upcoming, 
        pokemon_a_hp: pokemon_a.base_experience, 
        user_a_id: current_user.id)
    redirect_to arena_index_path
end

def new
    user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @pokemons = user.pokemons

    @pokemon_battle = PokemonBattle.new
end

def edit
    @pokemon_battle = PokemonBattle.find(params[:id])
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
resources :pokemon_battles, only: [:new, :create, :edit]
```

views/pokemon_battles/edit.html.slim

```
section
    = form_for @pokemon_battle do |f|
        - @pokemons.each do |pokemon|
            = f.radio_button :pokemon_b_id, pokemon.id 
            = f.label "pokemon_b_id_#{pokemon.id}", pokemon.name
            = f.submit 'Choose', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Comment: Did you forget about adding :update to route definition? `resources :pokemon_battles, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]`

Comment: Wow didn't know you had to include update before edit even works. Thanks